# Замена темы на работающем сайте

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет подскажите как правильно выполнить замену темы на работающем новостном портале, меня интересует именно логика действий так сказать. Имеем сайт с общим размером файлов 12 гб (картинки в основном) и 35 мб БД, нужно заменить установленную тему на новую при этом сохранить, если они нужны, плагины, а так же все посты. Тема платная и функциональная, но она отличается по функционалу от установленной, т.к. много чего допиливалось в шаблоны по мере необходимости, поэтому просто загрузить в папку с темами и нажать кнопку активировать не получится, точней получится но толку будет мало, её нужно допиливать до нужного фукционала. Как правильно это сделать? Делать бекап 12 гб и разворачивать на локалке, или загружать на субдомен, или же еще варианты? Потом разработка займет какое-то время, при этом на сайте будут публиковаться новости, их нужно тоже перенести на момент продакшена ) Подскажите кто как видит эту задачу?

Comment: Точная копия боевого сайта в качестве площадки для экспериментов должна быть не только на случай переезда, считается хорошим тоном вообще любые изменения сначала выполнять в тестовой среде, а потом уже переносить в боевую. @KAGGDesign всё правильно вам написал, так оно обычно и делается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наличие постов в базе никак на тему не влияет. Тема - это файлы и свои отдельные настройки в базе.

Переходить надо так. Сделать с помощью плагина Duplicator полный бэкап базы и картинок (чтобы видеть текущее состояние сайта), перенести на тестовый домен или локалку. Переключить тему, создать от неё дочернюю и допилить дочернюю, сравнивая с боевым сайтом. Когда всё будет готово, скопировать файлы основной и дочерней темы на боевой сайт и включить сначала основную (она может делать некую инициализацию), а потом дочернюю. Возможно, придётся перенести настройки новой темы, но это обычно одна огромная запись в таблице wp_options, в которой сериализован массив настроек темы. Остальную базу трогать не надо. Настройки темы можно вообще перенести вручную в админке за 5 минут.

Когда переключите боевой сайт на новую тему, все посты сохранятся, так что проблем с новыми постами нет.

Вот собственно, и всё. Сейчас, кстати, занимаюсь абсолютно аналогичной задачей. Сайт 26 ГБ, база 53 МБ, 35 плагинов.

Comment: Не все так гладко, получается установлено 60+ плагинов часть отключена, на новой теме может быть некоторые плагины отсеются и просто не будут использовать, плюс некоторые добавятся, многие из них используют бд и инфу могут писать в любую таблицу это же зависит от тараканов автора плагина. То есть выловить все таблицы в бд куда записаны данные плагинов, ну скажем тяжело. Получается после окончания нужно эту бд заливать на хостинг, я вот подумываю как быть с теми новостями которые будут опубликованы во время разработки сайта?

Comment: Все посты пишутся в таблицу wp_posts ? Если например сделать так когда будет все готово за разрабатываемом сайте, импортировать таблицу с постами из боего сайта в БД разрабатываемого и потом вместе с темой и плагинами загрузить все на хостинг.

Comment: Да при чем тут плагины. Пусть себе пишут. Не надо валить все в кучу. Займитесь темой сначала. Сделаете, перенесёте, потом будете разбираться с плагинами. Отделите мух от котлет, тогда будет все гладко.

Comment: Насчёт того, что посты пишутся в wp_posts - это и верно, и неверно. Ещё масса данных пишется в wp_post_meta. Пока нет полного понимания, как устроена база, лучше её не трогать от слова совсем.